# How to take input as an array from user in python using loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get an input from the user to store data in array. Let's say size of array is stored in a variable "n" and it is assigned 5. Now I want to have a size of array which will store only 5 values based on n but in run time. Like using arr = input() which should accept input separated by spaces not commas and that too in one line which means it should accept in like 1 2 3 4 5 and if I print arr I should get the above arr separated with commas [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
**input**

```
5 ( Size of Array)
1 2 3 4 2 2 2 (Array exactly like spaces entered in the shell)
```

```
array_elem = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
```

I tried this. I am not sure how to do it.

If I have to consider loops then, is this the correct way -

```
for i in range(5):
    arr = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
```

Comment: you can also try list comprehensions: `[int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]`

Comment: Let me try if that works @gavin

Comment: Sorry, what actually is the question? You say you tried some code - did it do what you expected? If not, what exactly went wrong?

Comment: @gavin This doesn't work. I can't write in input like ```1 2 3 2 2 2``` as an input in the shell

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I meant I wanted this input to be taken when I take array in loop n times which is size of an array. So if I try ```1 2 3 2 2 2``` as input it doesn't do anything. It is supposed to take this above complete thing as an array in python. Will this be possible?

Comment: in your example, you seem to be asking the user for the size of the input (5)...why?  the code above will chunk up an input of arbitrary size into a list of `int`s

Comment: @gavin I want in a single line input from user

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want in a single line input from user

Comment: @JeffH I am just illustrating an example with size say 5. Could be anything

Comment: @Shadowdev Please [edit] your question to clarify the exact behaviour you're looking for, including the exact input and desired output. How does your current code not fit your needs? See [mre] for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would use, you do not need the loop:

```
string = input()
arr = list(map(int, string.split(' ')))
```

Comment: What do you mean? That's exactly what OP did, just with an intermediate variable `string`.

Comment: It is less confusing. You just don't need the loop since it auto sizes with split.

Comment: @James Let me try once

Answer (score 1):

You can input the numbers with commas and then do a split:

```
>>> arr = list(map(int, input().split(',')))
1,2,3,4,5
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or you can do with spaces:

```
>>> arr = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
1 2 3 4 5
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Edit:**
If you want to use loop, then here is the code:

```
>>> n = int(input('How many elements: '))
>>> arr = []
>>> for _ in range(n):
...     arr.append(int(input()))
2
3
4
5
6
>>> arr
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work in loops. If I have to check the list should input only 5 times as much the size of array is then what ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to add arrays to the `arr`

```
arr=[]
for i in range(2):
    arr.append(list(map(int, input().split(' '))))
print(arr)
```

and its output for `1 2` ,`3 4` will be

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

if you are trying to add elements to the same `arr`

```
arr=[]
for i in range(2):
    arr+=(list(map(int, input().split(' '))))
print(arr)
```

and its output for `1 2` ,`3 4` will be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I ran it gave me this - 
```
1
2
[[1], [2]]
```

Comment: One line: `arr = [[int(x) for x in input().split(' ')] for _ in range(2)]`